# How to dynamically allocate a 2D array in one function and print it in another in C?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, printing, project, dynamic-allocation

I want to dynamically allocate a 2D array in one function and print it in another, but the return value of the createMapBoard() function needs to be a pointer to the array's address. Below is the code I have. It compiles and prints out, but only from the creatMapBoard() function. It won't read in the array to the printMapBoard(**char) function and I am not sure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char **createMapBoard(void);
void printMapBoard(char **board);
char **destroyMapBoard(char **board);

int main(){
    char **board = createMapBoard();
    printMapBoard(board);
    destroyMapBoard(board);
    printMapBoard(board);

    return 0;
}

char **createMapBoard(void){
    char **ptr[8][8];
    int i,j;
    char F = 'F';
    char K = 'K';
    char C = 'C';
    char D = 'D';
    char B = 'B';
    int n = 8;
    int m = 8;

    for(j=0; j<8; j++){
        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
            ptr[j][i] = ' ';
        }
    }

    ptr[0][0] = F;
    ptr[0][1] = F;
    ptr[1][1] = F;
    ptr[2][1] = F;
    ptr[2][2] = F;
    ptr[3][2] = F;
    ptr[4][2] = K;
    ptr[5][0] = C;
    ptr[5][3] = B;
    ptr[6][1] = C;
    ptr[6][2] = C;
    ptr[6][4] = D;
    ptr[7][2] = C;
    ptr[7][5] = D;
    ptr[7][6] = D;

    printf("========\n");

    for(j=0;j<8;j++){
        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
            printf("%c",ptr[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("========\n");
    printf("\n");

    return **ptr;
}

void printMapBoard(char **board){
    int j, i;
    printf("========\n");
    for(j=0;j<8;j++){
        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
            printf("%c", board[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("========\n");
    printf("\n");
}

char **destroyMapBoard(char **board){
    free(**board);
    free(board);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In `createMapBoard` you don't create anything dynamically. And your variable `ptr` is an array of 8 arrays of 8 pointers to pointers to `char`. Probably not exactly what you want.

Comment: Ok, how can I dynamically allocate the memory within the createMapBoard function then?

Comment: Have you tried searching for it? There are thousands of examples here on this site alone, probably millions all over the Internet. Try entering `c allocate 2d array dynamically example` into your favorite search engine and check the results.

Comment: example of pointer point to 2D-Array like [this](https://ideone.com/qsfnh4)

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to create 2D arrays in C. I've chosen the pointer to a pointer approach.

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>                                                                    
  2 #include <stdlib.h>                                                                   
  3                                                                                       
  4 const int row = 8;                                                                    
  5 const int col = 8;                                                                    
  6                                                                                       
  7 char **createMapBoard(void);                                                          
  8 void printMapBoard(char **board);                                                     
  9 int destroyMapBoard(char **board);                                                    
 10                                                                                       
 11 int main()                                                                            
 12 {                                                                                     
 13    char **board = createMapBoard();                                                   
 14                                                                                       
 15    printMapBoard(board);                                                              
 16    destroyMapBoard(board);                                                            
 17                                                                                       
 18    return 0;                                                                          
 19 }                                                                                     
 20                                                                                       
 21 char **createMapBoard(void)                                                           
 22 {                                                                                     
 23                                                                                       
 24    char **ptr;                                                                        
 25                                                                                       
 26    int i, j;                                                                          
 27                                                                                       
 28    char F = 'F';                                                                      
 29    char K = 'K';                                                                      
 30    char C = 'C';                                                                      
 31    char D = 'D';                                                                      
 32    char B = 'B';                                                                      
 33                                                                                       
 34    int n = 8; // rows                                                                 
 35    int m = 8; // columns                                                              
 36                                                                                       
 37    ptr = (char **)malloc( row * sizeof(char *) );                                     
 38    for (i = 0; i < row; ++i) {                                                        
 39       ptr[i] = (char *)malloc( col * sizeof(char *) );                                
 40    }                                                                                  
 41                                                                                       
 42    for (j = 0; j < row; j++){                                                         
 43       for (i = 0; i < col; i++) {                                                     
 44          ptr[j][i] = ' ';                                                             
 45       }                                                                               
 46    }                                                                                  
 47                                       
 48    ptr[0][0] = F;                                                                     
 49    ptr[0][1] = F;                                                                     
 50    ptr[1][1] = F;                                                                     
 51    ptr[2][1] = F;                                                                     
 52    ptr[2][2] = F;                                                                     
 53    ptr[3][2] = F;                                                                     
 54    ptr[4][2] = K;                                                                     
 55    ptr[5][0] = C;                                                                     
 56    ptr[5][3] = B;                                                                     
 57    ptr[6][1] = C;                                                                     
 58    ptr[6][2] = C;                                                                     
 59    ptr[6][4] = D;                                                                     
 60    ptr[7][2] = C;                                                                     
 61    ptr[7][5] = D;                                                                     
 62    ptr[7][6] = D;                                                                     
 63                                                                                       
 64    printf("========\n");                                                              
 65                                                                                       
 66    for (j = 0; j < row; j++) {                                                        
 67       for (i = 0; i < col; i++) {                                                     
 68         printf("%c",ptr[j][i]);                                                       
 69       }                                                                               
 70       printf("\n");                                                                   
 71    }                                                                                  
 72                                                                                       
 73    printf("========\n");                                                              
 74    printf("\n");                                                                      
 75                                                                                       
 76    return ptr;                                                                        
 77 }                                                                                     
 78                                                                                       
 79 void printMapBoard(char **board)                                                      
 80 {                                                                                     
 81    int j, i;                                                                          
 82    printf("========\n");                                                              
 83    for ( j = 0; j < row; j++) {                                                       
 84       for ( i = 0; i < col; i++) {                                                    
 85          printf("%c", board[j][i]);                                                   
 86       }                                                                               
 87       printf("\n");                                                                   
 88    }                                                                                  
 89    printf("========\n");                                                              
 90    printf("\n");                                                                      
 91 }                                                                                     
 92    
 93 int destroyMapBoard(char **board)                                                     
 94 {                                                                                     
 95    int i;                                                                             
 96    for (i = 0; i < col; ++i)                                                          
 97       free( board[i] );                                                               
 98                                                                                       
 99    free( board );                                                                     
100                                                                                       
101    return 0;                                                                          
102 }
```

Comment: "There are some ways to create 2D arrays in C" -- and yet there are no 2d arrays in this answer....

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * createMapBoard(void);
void printMapBoard(char board[8][8]);
char **destroyMapBoard(char board[8][8]);

int main(){
    char (*board)[8] = (char (*)[8])createMapBoard();
    printMapBoard(board);
    destroyMapBoard(board);
    //printMapBoard(board);

    return 0;
}    

char *createMapBoard(void){
    char (*ptr)[8] = (char (*)[8])malloc(sizeof(char) * 8 * 8);
    int i,j;
    char F = 'F';
    char K = 'K';
    char C = 'C';
    char D = 'D';
    char B = 'B';
    int n = 8;
    int m = 8;

    for(j=0; j<8; j++){
        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
            ptr[j][i] = ' ';
        }
    }

    ptr[0][0] = F;
    ptr[0][1] = F;
    ptr[1][1] = F;
    ptr[2][1] = F;
    ptr[2][2] = F;
    ptr[3][2] = F;
    ptr[4][2] = K;
    ptr[5][0] = C;
    ptr[5][3] = B;
    ptr[6][1] = C;
    ptr[6][2] = C;
    ptr[6][4] = D;
    ptr[7][2] = C;
    ptr[7][5] = D;
    ptr[7][6] = D;

    printf("========\n");

    for(j=0;j<8;j++){
        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
            printf("%c",ptr[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("========\n");
    printf("\n");

    return (char *)ptr;
}    

void printMapBoard(char board[8][8]){
    int j, i;
    printf("========\n");
    for(j=0;j<8;j++){
        for(i=0;i<8;i++){
            printf("%c", board[j][i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("========\n");
    printf("\n");
}

char **destroyMapBoard(char board[8][8]){
    free(board);

    return 0;
}
```

Before getting to your original question of how to allocate 2D arrays and pass it to another, your code is broken in several ways that make it difficult to talk about your original point.  Let us fix them first before getting to the point.

First and foremost, by having statement like ptr[j][i] = ' ', you presumably want to have a 2D array of chars, in which case you should declare ptr as such.

```
char ptr[8][8]; // 2D array of chars
```

not

```
char** ptr[8][8];  // 2D array of pointers to pointers to chars
```

Second if you want to return the array (ptr) you created inside createMapBorad, then you need to return ptr, not **ptr.  i.e.,

```
return ptr;
```

not

```
return ** ptr;
```

The expression ** ptr dereferences the ptr twice, which is equivalent to ptr[0][0] in this case, which will return 'F' (0x46) disguised as if it is a pointer to pointers to chars (char ** ).  your printMapBoard then accesses the address 0x46, which causes segfault.  This is almost certainly not what you meant to do.

After fixing them, if you want to return a "2D array of chars" rather than an array of pointers, you need to have createMapBoard return char* rather than char** .  char** is an array (pointer) of pointers (to chars).

So far, you at least need to fix createMapBoard to:

```
char * createMapBoard(void) {
    char ptr[8][8];
    ...
    return (char *)ptr;
}
```

(We are not done yet. stay tuned).

BTW, it would have been nice if you can say a function returns a 2D array, not char* (which is essentially 1D array, so you cannot do things like a[i][j]), but AFAIK C does not allow us to do this.  The following (hypothetical) code is a syntax error.

```
char[8][8] createMapBoard(void) {
    char ptr[8][8];
    ...
    return ptr;
}
```

So you need to pretend you return a regular 1D array (char* ).  You can cast it later to the real 2D array later (we are getting to it shortly).

After fixing createMapBoard this way, you are still making an error of returning a local array as the return value.  This is wrong because the lifetime of local arrays is limited to the end of the function invocation.  So the code

```
char * createMapBoard(void) {
    char ptr[8][8];
    ...
    return (char *)ptr;
}
```

is syntactically OK, but prints wrong results.

You need to call malloc to create an array that is alive after you return from the function, like:

```
char * createMapBoard(void) {
    char * ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 8 * 8);
    ...
    return ptr;
}
```

But then ptr essentially becomes a 1D array inside createMapBoard function, which makes assignments like

```
ptr[i][j] = ' '
```

no longer valid.

The way you can make ptr a 2D array is this:

```
char (*ptr)[8] = (char (*)[8])malloc(sizeof(char) * 8 * 8);
```

which is supported from C99 standard.

This way, the compiler understands ptr is a pointer to a 2D array whose number of elements in each row is eight (so it can correctly calculate the address of a[i][j]).

You can have printMapBorad simply take an argument of char[8][8] like this:

```
void printMapBorad(char board[8][8]) {
   ...
}
```

Summary:

- function arguments can be straightforwardly declared as 2D arrays (like char a[8][8])
- local variables can be declared as 2D arrays by char (* a)[8]; (and ordinary pointers casted similarly by (char (* )[8])ordinary_ptr;
- function return types cannot be declared as 2D arrays, AFAIK, so you need to pretend as if they are 1D arrays (and cast them to appropriate types as necessary)